# HTML Option Not Appending

Tags: javascript, html, forms, element

I am experimenting with bootstrap and building an HTML form with some javaScript. I've tried to strip down my issue for simplicity (in other words, I realize this seems like a useless form).

I'm basically trying to use javaScript to update the form's second item with a drop down selection (just one selection option for proof of concept). I'm using a click event just to test. If I were to hard code in selections such as:
`<option>first selection</option>` it works as expected.

I can see the click event is registering as it does update the first parameter, but it's not doing anything to the drop down menu. On W3schools it completes with the no visible change to the selection box while the Snipit on StackOverflow creates a load of errors that indicate it doesn't recognize getElementID (which seems strange since it **DOES** seem to recognize it to correctly address the first line of the click event).

Anyway... help appreciated and I'll be sure to accept. I"m sure I'm just doing something obviously wrong as I'm still pretty new at this.

```js
function afterButtonClicked() {
  //this works and is just to confirm my listener is done correctly (I think)
  var tEntry = document.getElementById("test_entry");
  tEntry.value = "successfully clicked at " + new Date();

  //this doesn't seem to do anything.
  //I am expecting my drop down to now have the option "first selection"
  var item = document.getElementbyId("my_selection");
  var myOption1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
  myOption.textContent = "first selection";
  item.appendChild(myOption);
}

document.getElementById("aButton").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="test_entry">This box works okay</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_entry">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="my_selection">I am trying to populate this drop down after a click</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="my_selection">
        </select>

      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="aButton">Create Some Drop Down Options</button>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm sure this is something easy. I'll be sure to accept an answer for whoever points out my wayward ways.

Comment: Typo: Change getElementbyId  to getElementById  in line  `var item = document.getElementbyId("my_selection")`

Comment: Ughh... I typed all of that up just to have it solved in 30 seconds. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two errors in your JS

Its `getElementById` and `myOption1` should be `myOption`

```
function afterButtonClicked() {

  //this works and is just to confirm my listener is done correctly (I think)
  var tEntry = document.getElementById("test_entry");
  tEntry.value = "successfully clicked at " + new Date();

  //this doesn't seem to do anything.
  //I am expecting my drop down to now have the option "first selection"
  var item = document.getElementById("my_selection");
  var myOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
  myOption.textContent = "first selection";
  item.appendChild(myOption);
}

document.getElementById("aButton").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wnxag1yz/

Comment: Thanks. The `myOption1` was something I partially added while writing this question. Of course, you're correct that it was wrong, but my main pain point was getElementByID. I'm going to accept your answer but be a good sport and go upvote something by xyz (from the comments section)  since he technically identified it first, but didn't post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Way ahead of you batman, and already upvoted him, but I was playing in Fiddle and just pasted answer before seeing his comment!